# Swift4: how to create global variables for my entire project including all the cocoapod libraries I have included

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I want to know how to create global variables for my entire project. My project has the usual viewcontroller files and also a couple of 3rd party cocoapod libraries.  I need to create some static global variables that are accessible both inside the cocoapod libraries as well as in the viewcontroller swift files.   Please help,

thanks, 
-Vittal

Comment: How will the 3rd party libraries know about these variables and reference them?

Comment: You want all import libs to be in one place ?

Comment: @phil: the 3rd party cocoapods are available as .swift files. I will do minor edits to these files so I can define a global static variable in one place ( dont where to define this) so that ALL files in my project, including the files in my cocoapods can see them.  Question is where should I define my global var so it is visible everywhere? I tried to do in appdelegate file as well as viewcontroller class.. no success

Comment: any replies to my above question?   Please help

Comment: Alternately, How do I pass information from a viewcontroller to a module ( cocoapod)